# Why small divs are not in the big div?

Tags: html, css, header, nav

Header should be the full width of the window, and invested in it divas have a total width of 980 pixels. 
But why three small divs are not in the big div? And is it possible to make the code easier?
Thanks for all the answers. jsfiddle.net/7L1kLagf

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="left">
                <nav class="left-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#one">One</a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                Pic
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <nav class="right-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#two">Two</a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

header{
background-color: black;
}

.center{
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 16px 0 0 0;
border: 5px;
}

.left{
float: left;
width: 325px;
border: 5px solid black;
}

.logo{
float: left;
width: 300px;
border: 5px solid black;
}

.right{
float: left;
width: 325px;
border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle to visualize your problem. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, of course. http://jsfiddle.net/7L1kLagf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have your inner elements set to float. If elements are set to float, the container will not "wrap" around them. You can use `display: table` on your container (header) and `display: table-cell` on your inner elements instead of trying to float them. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7L1kLagf/1/)

```
header{
    background-color: black;
    display: table;
}

.center{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    border: 5px;
}

.left{
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 325px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}

.logo{
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
}

.right{
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 325px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS: 
 Notice the changes to `width`

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

header{
background-color: black;
}

.center{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 16px 0 0 0;
border: 5px;
}

.left{
float: left;
width: 25%;
border: 5px solid black;
}

.logo{
float: left;
width: 44.5%;
border: 5px solid black;
}

.right{
float: left;
width: 25%;
border: 5px solid black;
}
```

You have to set the containing div to 100% and then set the smaller div's to take up a certain percent of the containing div. You should always use `%` over `px` so the screen fill is consistent.